# JPanel size problems, when I resize

Tags: java, image, swing, resize, jpanel

I have following code to display and draw `JPanel` with buffered image.

I am setting its size to size of buffered image, but it is not getting set actually.

It shows scroll bars when I resize, but when I resize `JFrame` greater than size of panel or `BufferedImage`, I am still getting mouse events when I click outside of panel's size.

I have omitted extra code.

```
    public class PaintFrame extends JFrame{    
        private JScrollPane paintScrollPane;
        private Painter painter;
        private JPanel paintPanel;
        private BufferedImage paintImage;
        private Color forgroundColor;

        public PaintFrame(){
            super("Paint");
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
            setLocationByPlatform(true);
            getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);

            paintImage = new BufferedImage(700, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

            paintPanel = new JPanel(){
                @Override
                public void paint(Graphics g){
                    if(paintImage != null){
                        g.drawImage(paintImage, 0, 0, paintImage.getWidth(), paintImage.getHeight(), null);
                    }
                }
            };
            paintPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
            paintPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me){
                    mouseClickedOnPaint(me);
                }
            });
            paintPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(paintImage.getWidth(), paintImage.getHeight()));
            paintScrollPane = new JScrollPane(paintPanel, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

            getContentPane().add(paintScrollPane);

            pack();
        }
}
```

Comment: After adding imports and commenting out `Painter`, I still get an error on `mouseClickedOnPaint(me);`.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Do you just have that on Paste? :P

Comment: @Quirliom  The last part of it?  Of course.  What, do you think I'm thick?

Comment: @AndrewThompson No Offence intended, just an amusing observation.

Comment: @Quirliom  *"just an amusing observation"*  ..join the queue.  ;)

Comment: @Meraman Don't use `paint` - especially if you're not going to call `super.paint`.  Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).  Also, avoid using `setPreferredSize`, instead, override the `getPreferredSize` method instead.  Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi) for more details

Comment: @Quirliom Andrew's actually a bot that automatically responds to all posts tagged with Swing.  And grateful we are ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Quirlom has pointed out, `LayoutManager`s may choice to ignore the `getPreferredSize` value based on the needs of there implementations

If all you're worried about is the mouse events, you could filter them out by determining if the mouse event clicked within the image or not.

Otherwise you need to find a layout manager that better meets your needs...

The following example simply determines if the mouse events fall within the bounds of the image...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ClickImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ClickImage();
    }

    public ClickImage() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new ImagePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ImagePane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage background;
        private List<Point> goodPoints;
        private List<Point> badPoints;

        public ImagePane() {
            try {
                background = ImageIO.read(new File("/Volumes/Disk02/Dropbox/MegaTokyo/url.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            goodPoints = new ArrayList<>(5);
            badPoints = new ArrayList<>(5);
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (getImageBounds().contains(e.getPoint())) {
                        goodPoints.add(e.getPoint());
                    } else {
                        badPoints.add(e.getPoint());
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void invalidate() {
            goodPoints.clear();
            badPoints.clear();
            super.invalidate();
        }

        public Rectangle getImageBounds() {
            Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle();
            if (background != null) {
                bounds.x = (getWidth() - background.getWidth()) / 2;
                bounds.y = (getHeight() - background.getHeight()) / 2;
                bounds.width = background.getWidth();
                bounds.height = background.getHeight();
            }

            return bounds;            
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return background == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : getImageBounds().getSize();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (background != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                Rectangle bounds = getImageBounds();
                g2d.drawImage(background, bounds.x, bounds.y, this);

                g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                drawPoints(g2d, goodPoints);
                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                drawPoints(g2d, badPoints);

                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

        protected void drawPoints(Graphics2D g2d, List<Point> points) {
            for (Point p : points) {
                g2d.drawLine(p.x - 4, p.y - 4, p.x + 4, p.y + 4);
                g2d.drawLine(p.x + 4, p.y - 4, p.x - 4, p.y + 4);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You may also want to take a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)